# Is the following the correct way to obtain unique id in app engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a legacy Google App engine code, which is having the following entity classes in Python

```
class AffiliateParent(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)

class Affiliate(db.Model):
    email = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    point_gain = db.IntegerProperty()
    point_used = db.IntegerProperty()
    #feature_upgrade = db.ListProperty(str)
    modified_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
```

I was wondering, is the following the correct way to generate unique id? Are they guarantee unique within `Affiliate` table?

```
affiliate_parent_key = AffiliateParent.all(keys_only=True).filter('name =', 'yancheng').get();
affiliate_parent = db.get(affiliate_parent_key);
# check whether affiliate exist, if not create one
affiliate_parent = db.get(affiliate_parent_key);

q = Affiliate.all()
q.ancestor(affiliate_parent)
q.filter('email =', email)
affiliate = q.get()

if not affiliate:
    affiliate = Affiliate(
        email = email,
        point_gain = 0,
        point_used = 0,
        parent = affiliate_parent
    )
    affiliate.put()

# 4503602445942784
# is this unique?
unique_id = affiliate.key().id()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, if you don't supply `id` or `key` when instantiating the model, then datastore will generate a unique ID and assign it to your entity when you `.put()` it... thus `affiliate.key.id()` will be unique

you can also generate unique IDs using `allocate_ids(count)`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids

Comment: Looks like it's in an entity group, so it's unique only within the entity group defined by `affiliate_parent`, right?